# Ubuntu 16.04.1 - HP Pavilion x360 Convertible PC - Wifi not working

Tags: networking, hp, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

So, a family member received a HP Pavilion x360 Convertible PC for Christmas.
For [Person] I dual booted it with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and the Preinstalled Win 10. I have not found a post or anything online about this issue (sort of). The first problem was the interface would not even show up and I found a post on that which basically said to install Kernel 4.7 and install `linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb`. So I did so and I am now able to see wlo1 (assuming the wifi device) so I went into system settings and as soon as I turn the wifi on, It switches off...
or in console this happens:

```
Person@NEWHPLAPTOP:~$ifconfig
lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 add: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
         RX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
         RX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)

Person@NEWHPLAPTOP:~$ifconfig -a
lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 add: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
         RX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
         RX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)

wlo1     Link uncap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:e3:7a:4a:c9:c3
         BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0 B)

Person@NEWHPLAPTOP:~$sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
Person@NEWHPLAPTOP:~$ifconfig
lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 add: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
         RX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:34564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
         RX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2557680 (2.5 MB)
```

FYI the wifi device is a Intel 3168NGW, works fine on windows

Thanks in advanced,
      VE5LPL

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I did http://askubuntu.com/a/849381/636969 and it works now...